# Python. Передача экземпляров в inner class

Tags: python, ооп, классы, вложенные-классы

Можно ли во внутреннем классе обратиться к экземпляру внешнего класса, без указания его в качестве атрибута конструктора внутреннего класса?

Рассмотрим пример

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, atr1):
        self.connect = f'connect A class {atr1}'
        
    class B:
        def __init__(self, time):
            self.time = time
            self.connect = super(A).connect
```

В результате ожидаю получить следующее:

```
obj_A = A('atr1')
obj_B1 = obj_A.B(10)
obj_B2 = obj_A.B(100)

print(obj_A.connect) # connect A class atr1
print(obj_B1.connect) # connect A class atr1
print(obj_B2.connect) # connect A class atr1
```

Возможно, мне не стоит использовать внутренний класс, а стоит рассмотреть другие принципы ООП?

Пробовал воспользоваться get методом, но не вышло ожидаемого результата.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, atr1):
        self.connect = f'connect A class {atr1}'

    class B:
        def __init__(self, time):
            super(A.B, self).__init__()
            self.time = time

    def get_B(self, time):
        return A(self).B(time)
```

```
obj = A('atr1')
obj2 = obj.B(222)
obj3 = obj.B(122)
```

Из обсуждения пришел к следующему:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, atr1):
        self.connect = f'connect A class {atr1}'


class B:
    def __init__(self, time, obj: A):
        self.time = time
        self.obj_A = obj
        self.connect = obj_A.connect

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj_A = A('atr1')
    obj_B1 = B(10, obj_A)
    obj_B2 = B(100, obj_A)
    print(obj_A.connect)  # connect A class atr1
    print(obj_B1.connect)  # connect A class atr1
    print(obj_B2.connect)  # connect A class atr1
```

Это работает, но не дает лаконичности кода для вызова объектов завязанных на родителе.

Comment: не очень понятно, чего вы хотите добиться. у вас получается, что объекты класса B должны быть зависимы от конкретного объекта класса А, а вовсе даже не от класса А

Comment: Да @splash58, вы правы. Нужна зависимость объектов B от A. Но не через атрибуты конструктора класса B, а через создание нового объекта B c указанием родительского экземпляра A.

Comment: я там вам написал ответ, который формально делает то, что вы спрашиваете в вопросе, но это ли вам надо?

Answer (score 0):

не очень понятно, чего вы хотите добиться. у вас получается, что объекты класса B должны быть зависимы от конкретного объекта класса А, а вовсе даже не от класса А

в явном виде то, что в спрашиваете, может быть реализовано вот так, ноя не очень понимаю смысл такого действа

```
def init(self, time):
    self.time = time

class A:
    def __init__(self, atr1):
        self.connect = f'connect A class {atr1}'
        self.B = type('B', (object,), {'connect': f'connect A class {atr1}', '__init__': init})


obj_A = A('atr1')
obj_B1 = obj_A.B(10)
obj_B2 = obj_A.B(100)

print(obj_A.connect)  # connect A class atr1
print(obj_B1.connect)  # connect A class atr1
print(obj_B2.connect)  # connect A class atr1
```

Comment: как вы заметили ранее, формально вывод соответствует ожидаемому результату

Comment: но не то что нужно. Меня интересует возможность вкладывать еще другие классы, объекты которых будут зависеть от объекта родителя и иметь возможность взаимодействовать с методами внешнего класса через экземпляр родителя.

Comment: и что вам мешает взаимодействовать?

Comment: и вообще, судя по второму комментарию, вам нужно при инициализации объекта класса B просто отдавать ссылку на нужный объект класса А

Comment: Если сделать два раздельных класса и передавать в B объект A как атрибут конструктора, все работает как надо, но это не внутренний класс и теряется лаконичность кода. 
Пример инициализации раздельных классов: 
`obj_A = A() 
obj_B = B(obj_A)` 
Пример инициализации внутреннего класса: 
`obj = A().B()`

Comment: вот так `b = B(obj_A,...)`